# How to remove scientific notation for <input type="number" step="0.00000001">, React JS?

Tags: reactjs, input

I am using ant design form in my reactJS application and I'd like to remove the scientific notation from my Input component?

Attaching the sample code

`<Input type="number" step="0.00000001"  />`

Output

[image]

Comment: With a step size that small, what is this input even used for? Because the best solution is almost certainly to not use an 8-decimal-places number input here.

Comment: I tend to go on the assumption that people actually need what they're asking for

Comment: Guess that touched a nerve!

Answer (score -1):

This is kind of a dumb solution, but it works: just read the value out of the field and write it back in again in the format you want.

```html
<input type="number" step="0.00000001" onchange="this.value=parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(8);" />
```